# Evaluate convergence radius for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$ $(3x - 2)^n \over 5^n(n+2)\sqrt{n+3}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

**Follow-up question (see "Edit")**

> Given
>
> $f(x) :=$ $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$ $(3x - 2)^n \over 5^n(n+2)\sqrt{n+3}$,
>
> I have to evaluate the largest open interval where $f(x)$ converges.

**Approach**

I guess I have to evaluate the convergence radius.

First, we note that

$\left({ (3x - 2)^n \over 5^n(n+2)\sqrt{n+3}}\right)^{1 \over n}$ = ${ 3x - 2 \over 5(n+2)^{1 \over n}\sqrt{n+3}^{1 \over n}}$ = ${ 3x - 2 \over 5(n+2)^{1 \over n}{(n+3)}^{1 \over n^2}}$

such that

$\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $\left|{ 3x - 2 \over 5(n+2)^{1 \over n}{(n+3)}^{1 \over n^2}}\right|$ = $\left| 3x - 2 \over 5 \right|$

and

$r = $ $1 \over \left| 3x - 2 \over 5 \right|$ = $\left|5 \over  3x - 2  \right|$.

That's what I solved so far - but what would be the last step here? For what $x$ does the series converge then?

**Edit**

Joanpemo mentioned that the power series would also converge for $x$ $=$ $7 \over 3$. But neither the root test nor the application gives me a useful result. (the critical value is $1$ in both cases) Is he mistaken there?

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/series/rootratio/rootratio.html

Comment: I have to solve $\left|5 \over  3x - 2  \right|$ $\lt 1$ then?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846654/how-to-solve-this-inequality-with-absolute-value-frac-leftx-3-right-lef/1846662#1846662

Comment: This gives me $x$ $\lt $ $7 \over 3$.

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy-Hadamard yo get

$$\frac1R=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac1{5^n(n+2)\sqrt{n+3}}\right|}=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\frac1{5\sqrt[n]{(n+2)(n+3)^{1/2}}}=\frac15$$

And thus the convergence radius is $\;R=5\;$ , so the power series converges at

$$|3x-2|<5\iff -3<3x<7\iff-1<x<\frac73$$

Check now end points of $\;\left[-1,\,\frac73\right]\;$ , say:

$$x=-1\implies \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-5)^n}{5^n(n+2)\sqrt{n+3}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+2)\sqrt{n+3}}$$

and this last converges as it is a Leibniz series. Check that also at $\;x=\frac73\;$ you get convergence, so the convergence *interval* is $\;\left[-1,\,\frac73\right]\;$ .

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :-) Why does the numerator of $f(x)$ disappear when you apply Cauchy-Hadamard? And how do you conclude $|3x - 2| \lt 5$?

Comment: Oh, I guess it didn't disappear, you simply added it later on since the evaluation of its critical value is trivial. Overall, you get $|3x - 2| \over 5$ $\lt 1$, and this is, of course, equivalent to $|3x - 2| \lt 5$.

Comment: @Julian It doesn't "dissapear". Cauchy-Hadamard formula is for **the coefficients** of a power series, which is *almost* what you have here (you have it, but you would have to write $\;(3x-5)^n=3^n\left(x-\frac53\right)^n\;$ , so as we can see this as **an actual power series** of $\;x\;$ around the point $\;x_0:=\frac53\;$

Comment: Is there a mistake in my own approach above? It might be not that beautiful as yours, but it's correct nonetheless, isn't it?

Comment: @Julian I think your approach is just fine, but the last line where $\;r\;$ appears is odd, as you seem to remember the C-H formula, as mentioned, but for this you *only* apply the $\;n\,-$ th root to the coefficients of the power series, not to the whole thing. Anyway, when you reach the limit then *you want that* it is less than one, so $$\left|\frac{3x-2}5\right|<1\iff |3x-2|<5$$ and then you continue as I did in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while since I worked with power series. :-) I still have trouble with understanding your representation of Cauchy-Hadamard.  You just said that one applies it to the coefficients of the power series - and $(3x - 2)^n$ is one of them. Why did you exclude it in your examination in the first line then? Although it looks like you applied the $n-th$ root to it, I don't see where you did this actually.

Comment: @Julian It is as follows: for a power series around the point $\;x_0\;$ :$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-x_0)^n$$ its radius of convergence $\;R\;$ is given by $$R=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}$$ with the convention that $\;R=\infty\;$ if the above supreme limit is zero, and $\;R=0\;$ if the above supreme limit is infinity. Observe that the above, called Cauchy-Hadamard formula, is **only for** the $\;n\,-$ th root of the *coefficients' sequence* of the power series, and that's what I did.

Comment: But where does $|3x - 2|$ come from then? It seems like you didn't apply the n-th root on it before.

Comment: @Julian  And I don't need to apply it on this. Sorry, I just cannot develop the whole theory of power series, a very beautiful, important and basic one. Maybe you could google it.

Comment: You're right, I will figure it out myself. :-) Thank you for your patience!